# How to create coupon for the Configurable Product/Products. magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, coupon

I'm applying **coupon** on the configurable product like [image]

now when I apply this coupon on the specific **product** then it cannot be applied and gives me an error

> The coupon code "Code-5cd3eadf39cda" is not valid.

but if I remove the **Quantity** as I mention in the image then the coupon works what is the probem? 
**Note :** This coupon code works perfectly on the **simple product**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to fix the quantity in **Actions** not in **Conditions** In image I express it.
[image]